# Who are the two dead Georgia voters who voted?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, election-fraud, contested-election

> It was clear from the call that Trump has surrounded himself with aides who have fed his false perceptions that the election was stolen. When he claimed that more than 5,000 ballots were cast in Georgia in the name of dead people, Raffensperger responded forcefully: "The actual number was two. Two. Two people that were dead that voted."

[Source](https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/politics/i-just-want-to-find-11-780-votes-in-extraordinary-hour-long-call-trump-pressures-georgia-secretary-of-state-to-recalculate-the-vote-in-his-favor/ar-BB1cqNSk)

Who are these two people? From a brief search, all the details I could find date from November 2020, e.g. [this article](https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/politics/georgia-investigating-two-cases-of-dead-people-voting/ar-BB1aZZzB?fbclid=IwAR0vEK8OKPDfYtQUIOaSyrNUVS3wWvt8T412uriNVCj4SzqakqwxfeTeeTo):

> One Dade County man, Edward Skwiot, who died in 2015 at age 82, was issued a mail-in ballot on Oct. 1, which state records show was accepted on Oct. 19.
>
> County Executive Ted Rumley said the case was now under investigation by the sheriff’s office.

However, I couldn't find the results of the investigation (or confirmation that Edward Skwiot is indeed one of the two dead voters), or the name of the other dead person that voted.

Comment: Let the courts handle this please; it's not really a question of politics. Voting to close.

Comment: I don't see why this is something for the courts to handle. The question simply asks for details about these two people, which is not a legal question. It's also clearly related to a political topic. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @Allure I don't see how the question who the two persons were is a political question. Unless, maybe, if the persons suspected of having cast votes in their name are persons of public interest.

Comment: Personally, I think this should be closed under the "could not be verified with sources available to the public" close reason.  It's certainly related to the election and the politics of it's validity, but unless there's either an actual announcement or a court filing, there's not really any way for us to know the answer.

Comment: @Bobson there has been media coverage of some of the other alleged dead voters, however (https://factcheck.afp.com/team-trumps-dead-voters-georgia-3-falsehoods-1-truth) so it's not inconceivable to me that details would be available of the two actual dead voters.

Comment: @Hulk See above comment - if the alleged dead voters are of public interest (they presumably are since the media covered them), I don't see why the actual dead voters would not be of public interest.